# MySQL - Deduct result of one query from result of another

Tags: mysql

I have two queries that I am running.

Here they are:

**First query**

```
SELECT SUM(dbase1.transaction.amount) AS total, dbase1.player.name 
FROM dbase1.transaction
JOIN dev2.player ON dbase1.transaction.player_id = dbase1.player.player_id
WHERE (dbase1.transaction.type !=1)
AND (dbase1.transaction.type !=3) 
GROUP BY dbase1.transaction.player_id 
ORDER BY name ;
```

**And the second query**

```
SELECT dbase2.transaction.amount
, dbase2.transaction.player_id
, dbase2.player.name 
FROM dbase2.transaction
JOIN dbase2.player ON dbase2.transaction.player_id = dbase2.player.player_id
WHERE dbase2.transaction.provider ='providerx';
```

In the first result set I get an amount and a name, in the second I get an amount, a name and an ID.

What I want is to deduct the amount from the second set of results from the first, where the names match.

So essentially my final result would be:

```
amount from set1 - amount from set2, name, id
```

I hope this makes sense and any advice would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just join them.

```
select a.total - b.amount from (
    select sum(dbase1.transaction.amount)
    as total, dbase1.player.name from dbase1.transaction
    JOIN dev2.player on
    dbase1.transaction.player_id = dbase1.player.player_id
    where
    (dbase1.transaction.type !=1)
    and
    (dbase1.transaction.type !=3) group by dbase1.transaction.player_id
) query_a a
INNER JOIN 
(
    select dbase2.transaction.amount, dbase2.transaction.player_id, dbase2.player.name from dbase2.transaction
    JOIN dbase2.player ON
    dbase2.transaction.player_id = dbase2.player.player_id
    where dbase2.transaction.provider ='providerx'
) query_b b on a.name = b.name
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use your two queries as derived tables and do this:

```
select 
    q1.total - q2.amount, q2.name, q2.player_id 
from (
    select 
       sum(dbase1.transaction.amount) as total, 
       dbase1.player.name 
    from dbase1.transaction
    join dev2.player on dbase1.transaction.player_id = dbase1.player.player_id
    where 
       (dbase1.transaction.type !=1)
       and
       (dbase1.transaction.type !=3) 
    group by dbase1.transaction.player_id
    ) q1
join (
    select 
       dbase2.transaction.amount, 
       dbase2.transaction.player_id, 
       dbase2.player.name 
    from dbase2.transaction
    join dbase2.player on dbase2.transaction.player_id = dbase2.player.player_id
    where dbase2.transaction.provider ='providerx'
    ) q2 on q1.name = q2.name
```